# How to Run cmd as admin and pass command to it?

Tags: c#, .net, command-prompt, privileges, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To run cmd as administrator along with command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610727/to-run-cmd-as-administrator-along-with-command)

I want to run a cmd using administrator privileges
and then pass the command to the process that is running cmd as administrator.

I don't want to use proc.standardinput to pass the command is there any other method?

Comment: @SBlackler i want to store the ssl certificates in trusted root and it require admin privileges i will do this using cmd

Comment: I assume this should be possible if the program calling `cmd` is already running with admin privs. Else this sounds a lot like you trying to elevate your privs, which should not be possible for security reasons.

Comment: You asked the same question twice. You need to delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the next api function from advapi32.dll [CreateProcessAsUser](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/CreateProcessAsUser.html)