# How to run command in the process which is executed with admin rights?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, user-permissions, makecert

I want to create **a self signed certificate** and install it using through c# program.
I use **makecert** to make certificate i run it as **administrator** and i pass command in the **ProcessStartInfo.argument** but the command doesn't executes what is the problem in the code?

Here is my code:

```
 public void Createasnewadmin()
 {

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

        Process p = new Process();          

        info.FileName = Application.StartupPath+@"\makecert.exe";

        info.UseShellExecute = true;

        info.Verb = "runas"; // Provides Run as Administrator

        info.Arguments = "makecert testCert_admin_check.cer";

        //i just create sample certificate but it doesn't get created
        //The problem is above line the command doesn't get execute 

        p.StartInfo=info;

        p.Start()

  }
```

**Please Tell me where is the problem is it not executing as administrator? or the command to be executed is not passed properly?**

I think it is executing as admin as i myself click on yes button to execute as admin that is prompted by windows

Why is command not executing? is there any other way?

Comment: some what similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610727/to-run-cmd-as-administrator-along-with-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your code, I suspect you are getting an error because your arguments are incorrect.

You line

```
info.Arguments = "makecert testCert_admin_check.cer";
```

should be

```
info.Arguments = "testCert_admin_check.cer";
```

Comment: Hey thanks it was the problem than it worked now, i want to execute two commands is it Possible if it is then how to do?I tried below method but didnt work                                     info.Arguments = "-n \"CN=My_Root_CA_1_admin_try ,O=Organization,OU=Org Unit,L=San Diego,S=CA,C=US\" -pe -ss my -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange -m 96 -a sha1 -len 2048 -r My_Root_CA_1_admin_try.cer" + "&& certutil.exe -f -addstore Root My_Root_CA_1_admin_try.cer";                                        I want to run this command to store the certificate in trusted root?

Comment: Great, glad that sorted you out. I think your next point is probably better suited as another question. But I would probably create a batch file which takes a few arguments and then execute the batch file from the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to supply credentials to invoke process in admin mode.

> UserName = "Administrator", Password = ,

Comment: i did verify it there is no problem in administrator privilege as i did run cmd using the same code and it did run as admin properly but then i could not pass commands to it through my program