# cmd.exe will not recognize command

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have a vb.net application that runs cmd.exe as the following:

```
Dim Port1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Port1.Run("cmd.exe")
    Port1.Sendkeys("telnet ip address")
    Port1.Sendkeys("{Enter}")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000)
```

When the cmd runs the sendkeys a error shows

"'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I closed the cmd window, opened another cmd, and typed in the command with not problems.

I need cmd to run in the vb.net and not as a separate file.

Running the vb.net in Microsoft visual studio Ultimate 2013.

**Update:** Can anyone tell me why it is doing the same thing when i move the app to another computer and try to run it?

Comment: check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807429/running-cmd-commands-with-administrator-rights

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are running the 32-bit version of cmd.exe.  Project + Properties, Compile tab.  Change the Target CPU setting to AnyCPU and untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option.

Comment: @HansPassant Your crystal ball can see far. I thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either Telnet is not installed on your computer (it's not installed by default on any modern Windows versions as far as I know), or it its installation directory not in the PATH environment variable.

Either add it's install directory to PATH, or specify the full path to telnet.exe in the arguments to cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable telnet on the computer by going to start > control panel > programs and features > turn windows feature on or off > check telnet client or typing optionalfeatures in run and checking telnet client. The command should execute successfully after that.

Answer (score -1):

CMD runs commands based off of System32 and .bat(batch) or .exe. You would have to create a .exe or a .bat and place it into System32 in order for the command to work.