# Cmd.exe issue with published Application

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have an issue that presented itself with an earlier post: [cmd.exe will not recognize command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847524/cmd-exe-will-not-recognize-command)

I fixed to problem by unchecking the prefer 32-bit box and if worked. 
Now I am trying to run the application and the problem represents itself.

Is there to fix this simply?

Comment: After reading your comments, maybe a simple batch file or PowerShell script might do the trick.

Comment: Would love to but everything has to be in the Source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the problem was "fixed" using that method earlier. The reason why that error message comes up is, by default, telnet is not enabled.

You have to enable telnet on the computer by going to start > control panel > programs and features > turn windows feature on or off > check telnet client. The command should execute successfully after that.

Comment: That fixed it somewhat. Now it is just taking too long to connect and messes up that way.

Comment: How slow is it if you just type the command into command prompt?

Comment: It is for work. They want a GUI interface that does this work and I have only recently started using VB.net. The App work perfectly on my computer but when another computer run it, it keeps opening cmd.exe.   I kind of want to find a wall and start banging my head into it...

Comment: Tried extending the time after is trying to connect to the telnet before inputting the next command and not it is going back to want it was doing before I activated the telnet client feature.

Comment: Try to do a telnet via command prompt on another user's computer. If it fails on their computer, then it the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: It tries to connect but fails. Did again on my computer and works. The telnet client is on.

Comment: So if the an alternate computer tries to connect via telnet in the command prompt and it fails, the issue is not with your program. I would test connectivity issues on that alternate computer.

Comment: You could try to ping the address you are trying to telnet into and see what it returns. If that works then try to telnet via a different port. It could also be that the remote computer is only accepting telnet requests from certain machines or IP addresses.