# How to run some CMD commands one by one (As admin)

Tags: c#, cmd, command

I have a few commands I want to run through the CMD (admin):

`ipconfig/flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset`

Anyone can tell me how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elevating process privilege programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question of is sort answered here: [Running cmd commands with Administrator rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807429/running-cmd-commands-with-administrator-rights)

The code could be duplicated (as shown below):

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C ipconfig /flushdns";
    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

System.Diagnostics.Process process2 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo2 = new 
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo2.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo2.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo2.Arguments = "/C ipconfig /renew";
    startInfo2.Verb = "runas";
    process2.StartInfo = startInfo2;
    process2.Start();
```

Comment: This run the CMD commands as administrator, right? (even if the user didn't chose "run as administrator")

Comment: And there is an error on: process2.StartInfo2 = startInfo2;

Comment: Should be process2.StartInfo = startInfo2

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use powershell, you can create a script which will include your commands something like this:

`& "command 1";`
`& "command 2";`
etc.