# Get input From User and Paste in it Command Prompt | Python

Tags: python, user-interface, logging, user-input, command-prompt

I am new in this Language. So I want to Write a Python App. Which will get input From User and Paste it in the CMD step by step. Cause I have Multiple Input.

What I need to Know:

1. Suppose I give something command like "date" and cmd is asking me the new date. so I need to take the value before execute the command for user.
2. Similar i Want to take 2-3 input from the user before execute the command than the command will be Execute and the asking things from cmd will be filled up by Python automatically.
3. I also want to do it in background .Dont want that user is watching the programme is using cmd.
4. Want to Show log in GUI. Like First input is pasting... second input is pasting... pasted!

**Advance Thanks to All Mates**

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
command = input("Enter the command to be executed on CMD : ")
os.system(f'cmd /c "{command}"') #Executes the command on CMD which is running in  background and it gets closes as soon as the output is generated
```

The above code won't open up the CMD and type the command but rather execute CMD in background and would print the output of command.

For example :

```
>>> Enter the command to be executed on CMD : net user
>>> User accounts for \\DESKTOP-XYZ

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            DefaultAccount           Guest
USER1                    USER2                    GuestAcc
The command completed successfully.
```

And if you'd like to store the output of the command in a text  file then
replace
`os.system(f'cmd /c "{command}"')` with `os.system(f'cmd /c "{command}>txt_file_name.txt"')`

So the final code if you'd also like to store the output would be:

```py
import os
command = input("Enter the command to be executed on CMD : ")
os.system(f'cmd /c "{command}>txt_file_name.txt"') 
'''
It executes the command and stores the output in .txt file named as 'txt_file_name.txt' 
which is saved in the same path as of the source code
'''
```

There are also some commands which need admin permissions to be executed. For those commands above code would return an error and would not execute properly. If you wish to  execute the admin commands then you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909472/how-to-run-some-cmd-commands-one-by-one-as-admin)

Comment: if there are multiple input thn?

Comment: What you mean by multiple inputs?

Comment: Is it like if the cmd is asking you for some input?

Comment: If it's that then python has no interaction with CMD that way

Comment: think i have c code of addition i want to write a code in python that paste the input taking from users so i need to get 2-3 input and paste it one but one when it needes.

you can say i can do that with c easily .but i told i want to learn python

Comment: or i wanted to go a directory in 2 steps and the directory is like "/first/second"
so i have to command like this `->cd first` and thn `->cd second` so i need to get the true directory name from user first...

Comment: So, do you want to take multiple inputs from the user and then execute it one by one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226824/discussion-between-shakil-ahmed-and-gamedev).