# Unable to run commands as admin

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to run some commands within my C# program but get an "access denied" error when I try to cd. I read that changing UseShellExecute to be true would give me admin access but whenever I do that I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' in System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
```

I've tried setting cmd.UserName to null and cmd.Verb to "runas" but still get that same error.  I'm also running visual studio as an admin. The issue is not with how to get admin access but why do I get an exception when I try to run it as an admin

```
ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Process console = Process.Start(cmd);
console.StandardInput.WriteLine(" cd ..");
```

Comment: possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807429/running-cmd-commands-with-administrator-rights)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running cmd commands with Administrator rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807429/running-cmd-commands-with-administrator-rights)

Comment: I've seen this one but it doesn't help me with the exception I'm getting

Comment: Is your C# program, which starts the command prompt, running as an administrator?

Comment: What´s your .NET platform version?

Comment: @BerBar I think its 4.7.03056

Comment: @RyanWilson I believe so, I'm running it using visual studio 2017 which I ran as an administrator

Comment: @mike if you examine the exception object, does it give you more information in the stack trace?

Comment: @RyanWilson Yeah, I can see the message is "UseShellExecute is not supported on this platform"

Comment: @Mike are you running this program on a Windows operating system?

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes, Windows 10