# Process not running as administrator

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
Dim pi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
pi.FileName=(ipchangepath)
pi.RedirectStandardError = True
pi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
pi.Verb = "runas"
pi.CreateNoWindow = true
pi.UseShellExecute =False
Dim p As process=Process.Start(pi) 

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(errorpath, p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(), True)
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(errorpath, p.StandardError.ReadToEnd(), True)
```

I am trying to run a batch file from my vb.net application but it requires administrator privileges to run.

I tried the above code but the error shows that it needs to be run as administrator

```
C:\Users\JONAH\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\LinkIt\LinkIt\bin\Debug>netsh interface ip set address name=Wi-Fi source=static addr=10.10.118.161 mask=255.255.254.0 gateway=10.10.116.25 gwmetric=0 
The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator).


C:\Users\JONAH\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\LinkIt\LinkIt\bin\Debug>netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static 10.10.116.5 
The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator).


C:\Users\JONAH\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\LinkIt\LinkIt\bin\Debug>netsh interface ip add dns "Wi-Fi" 202.200.100.95 index=2 
The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator).
```

Comment: Chris Haas' answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7610727/592111) will help I think.

Comment: The above solution hasn't helped.I get the same error