# connect compmgmnt.msc to remote host using c#

Tags: c#, cmd, mmc, runas

how can i use compmgmnt.msc to remote host using c#.
i found this...

execute this command in "cmd.exe" it is working and ask you for The password:

```
/user:administrator \"mmc.exe compmgmt.msc /computer:IZADI-PC\
```

but i need to know how can i use this command in c#.
i also need to pass the password to this command using c#.
i have username and password of the remote computer and i wanna do everything  programatically.

I also visited :

http://www.lansweeper.com/forum/yaf_postst5116_Runas-Custom-Actions.aspx
[Process.Start with different credentials with UAC on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313553/process-start-with-different-credentials-with-uac-on)

Thank you in advanced!!!

anyone write sample code to excecute `/user:administrator \"mmc.exe compmgmt.msc /computer:IZADI-PC\` in c#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106628/start-process-with-administrator-right-in-c-sharp

Comment: it is not what i'm looking for!!!

Comment: any help just somone said how run "/user:administrator \"mmc.exe compmgmt.msc /computer:IZADI-PC\" in c#

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                Process myprocess = new Process();
                myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myprocess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myprocess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                myprocess.StartInfo.UserName = "administrator";
                myprocess.StartInfo.Password = MakeSecureString("123456");
                myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k mmc.exe compmgmt.msc /computer:PC135-PC";
                myprocess.Start();
                myprocess.Close();
```