# Run new process as admin and read standard output

Tags: c#

I want to allow users to run a command line utility as administrator from within my non-admin program and for my program to get the output. The utility is third-party but is distributed with my programme.

I can [redirect the output of a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) and I can [run a program as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically) but I can't do both at the same time.

The only thing that I can get to work at the moment is using cmd.exe to redirect the output to a file, e.g.:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

string appDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string utilityPath = Path.Combine(appDirectory, "tools", "utility.exe");
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

Process p = new Process();
// hide the command window
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
// run the tool, redirect the output to the temp file and then close.
p.StartInfo.Arguments = " /C \"\"" + utilityPath + "\" > \"" + tempFile + "\"\"";
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // run as administrator
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

// get the output, delete the file and show the output to the user
string output = File.ReadAllText(tempFile);
File.Delete(tempFile);
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

This has two problems: 1) it uses a temporary file and 2) the UAC is for cmd.exe rather then utility.exe. There must surely be a better way to do this?

Comment: I think what I failed to make clear was the privileged difference. My application runs as standard user and the utility runs as administrator. As far as I can tell the normal way to redirect output doesn't work in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of executing through a new `cmd`, try executing the utility directly. And instead of  redirecting to a file, redirect the standard output to read it from your program.
In order to run as admin, you'll need to use the admin username and password (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4144445/1096117)). You'll need to set your method as `unsafe`:

```
unsafe public static void Main(string[] args){
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    // set admin user and password
    p.StartInfo.UserName = "adminusername";
    char[] chArray = "adminpassword".ToCharArray();
    System.Security.SecureString str;
    fixed (char* chRef = chArray) {
        str = new System.Security.SecureString(chRef, chArray.Length);
    }
    p.StartInfo.Password = str;
    // run and redirect as usual
    p.StartInfo.FileName = utilityPath;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: You should use `using(Process p = new Process())` or call `p.Dispose()` after `p.WaitForExit()`.

Comment: I get the error "The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams". So I add "p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;" but then that stops it running as administrator: "The requested operation requires elevation".

Comment: So I'd have to ask the user for the admin username and password instead of using the UAC? And they'd have to have activated the admin account and a set up a password?

Comment: If there is a better way I'm afraid I don't know

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it does answer the question but on balance I think I'll stick with my original idea. Asking for an admin account is not really going to be practical.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide) does the magic, although I haven't tested it.

It's written in C++, but a wrapper API can easily be created to be called from C# by using `DllImport`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The main idea is:

1. Create a wrapper script (such as `cmd` file) that calls the original command but redirects output stream to file.
2. Execute the wrapper script using `Process`.
3. Read the output stream file and then delete it.

To have a better way, you can encapsulate the whole thing in a class so that all the above tricks can occur under the hood. I have a working code example:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the script as admin. It blocks the control flow while executing.
        /// </summary>
        public void ExecuteAsAdmin()
        {
            this.Close();

            // Wrapper script is required for both executing the actual script as admin and
            // redirecting the error output simultaneously.
            string wrapperScriptFileName = this._fileName + "_exe.cmd";
            string stderrFileName = this._fileName + "_err.txt";

            try
            {
                File.Create(stderrFileName).Dispose();
                CreateWrapperScript(wrapperScriptFileName, stderrFileName);
                ExecuteWrapperScript(wrapperScriptFileName, stderrFileName);
            }
            finally
            {
                File.Delete(wrapperScriptFileName);
                File.Delete(stderrFileName);
            }
        }

        private void CreateWrapperScript(string wrapperScriptFileName, string stderrFileName)
        {
            StreamWriter wrapperScriptStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(wrapperScriptFileName);
            // redirect error output to file
            wrapperScriptStreamWriter.WriteLine(
                "\"" + Path.GetFullPath(this._fileName) + "\" 2> \"" + Path.GetFullPath(stderrFileName) + "\"");
            wrapperScriptStreamWriter.Close();
        }

        private void ExecuteWrapperScript(string wrapperScriptFileName, string stderrFileName)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = wrapperScriptFileName,
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Verb = "runas"
            };
            using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
            {
                if (process != null)
                {
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    this.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
                    this.StandardError = File.ReadAllText(stderrFileName);
                }
            }
        }
```

[Here](https://github.com/arnobpl/SymlinkCreator/blob/master/SymlinkCreator/core/ScriptExecutor.cs) is the full solution class code as an example.