# Launch application with admin rights from service with admin rights

Tags: c#

I have to launch application with admin rights (without UAC !) from service with has granted admin rights. Is there any way to that ? I read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106628/start-process-with-administrator-right-in-c-sharp) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp) article but that wasn't helpful for me.

Comment: Why weren't they helpful and presumably you mean a service running under an account with admin permissions...

Comment: Yes I mean service running under an account with admin permissions. When I running that code I see UAC dialog !

Comment: A few questions to clarify. When you say "From a service" do you mean [this kind of service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service)? 2ndly can you please show your code that launches the 2nd application that causes the UAC prompt. 3rd how is the "Service" being started and when does the UAC prompt show up? Services normally can't interact with the desktop so I am confused *how* the UAC was being shown.

Comment: Did you tried with `UserName` and `Password` approach?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the only way to stop UAC coming up, is to turn it of, or to not ned it to. That's the point of it.